# Is it possible to access my comment outbox?

Tags: support, comments

Is it possible to access my outbox to search for a comment I made?

I've tried searching my inbox for the conversation I'm looking for, but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  On your profile, first go to the "activities" tab and then choose the "comments" sub-tab.  This will show you a date-ordered list of comments you've posted that have not been deleted.  (Like deleted posts, deleted comments don't show up on your profile.)

[image: activities tab on user profile]

If you've never looked around in "activities" (used to be called "activity") before, check it out -- all your posts, reviews, edits, and more are there.

Comment: Thanks! I miss out on so much by visiting this site almost exclusively on the mobile format.

Comment: You can access the "tabs" on the mobile web interface too.  Near the top on the right, across from your name, you should see "show" followed by a link, which defaults to "summary".  Tap that and you'll get a list of options corresponding to the tabs.  Pick the one you want.

Comment: Wow. Beautiful. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome.  If you've reached 10k in 8 months using mostly mobile then it is *I* who should be commending *you*.  I posted from my phone once... ouch.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Is there a way to do a _search_ through my comments?  I have lots of comments, going through all of them to find a specific one would be tedious and time consuming.

Comment: @yEz oh I wish.  Short of using SEDE, which is based on the weekly data dumps so can be slightly out of date, I don't know of a way.  The search built into the site doesn't search comments at all (neither yours nor anybody else's), so I suspect that adding this would be hard.  Maybe an "export my comments" function would be feasible (you could request it) -- or I wonder if that's scriptable?